# Binding dependency property using XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Inside my user control MainControl I have dependency property named Repository. I want to bind this repository property in MainWindow using xaml

```
<my:MainControl x:Name="mainControl" Repository="{Binding }" Visibility="Visible" />
```

and inside MainWindow.xaml.cs I have

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _repository = new CarRepository();
    DataContext = _repository;
}
```

Inside MainControl constructor I was thinking to display some text using

```
public MainControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblCountCars.Content = string.Format("there is {0} cars.", Repository.CountAllCars());
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here `Repository="{Binding }"`? When I register user control inside code behind everything is ok but I want to learn how to do this using xaml.

**Update**
To make it clear. I have `MainWindow` which uses two user controls. `MainControl` and `TreassureControl`.
I want to send repository which is of type `ICarRepository` to any of this controls, so I created DependencyProperty named `Repository` of type `ICarRepository` both in `MainControl` and `TreassureControl`.

My goal is to send repository instance to `MainControl` `Repository` property (DP) and to print on label Content property `lblCountCars.Content = Repository.CountAllCars();`

Also I want this repository instance in user control to further work, not only to show simple text.

So I tried with suggestions bellow

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <my:MainControl x:Name="mainControl" Repository="{Binding Repository}" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private ICarRepository _repository;   
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _repository = new CarRepository(); 
   DataContext = _repository;
}
```

MainControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="mainControl">
<Label Name="lblCountBooks" Content="{Binding ElementName=mainControl, Path=Repository.CountAllBooks()}" 
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainControl, Path=Repository}" />
```

MainControl.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Repository",
            typeof(ICarRepository),
            typeof(MainControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ICarRepository Repository
        {
            get { return (ICarRepository)GetValue(RepositoryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RepositoryProperty, value); }
        }
```

label content is not updated with expected content.

Comment: pls post your relevant xaml for your MainControl, maybe the code for your DP too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when ever working with dependency properties in usercontrols i use elementname binding for binding to the DP. so i would remove your

> lblCountCars.Content = string.Format("there is {0} cars.",
>   Repository.CountAllCars());

and do something like this:

```
 <UserControl x:Name="uc">
   ...      
   <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Repository.Count}"/><!-- you can use ContentStringFormat here to get you formattet string-->
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Reportsitory}"/>
```

your binding in your mainwindow looks right.

EDIT:
you can just bind to properties. so instead of Repository.CountAllBooks() you need a property. if you dont have a chance to create a property on your ICarRepository, you can use a converter and the Repository property as convertparameter to get your info.

Answer (score 1):

This could be that your MainControls data context is not set in the constructor. You need to use the DataContextChanged event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
public MainControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += MainControl_DataContextChanged;
}

void MainControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblCountCars.Content = string.Format("there is {0} cars.", Repository.CountAllCars());    
}
```